# Access service running on localhost in Azure VM

Tags: azure, networking, azure-devops

I have a service using localhost deployed on Azure VM. I removed any restrictions on ports, allowed all inbound and outbound connections. I can ssh into the machine. However, I want to use the public IP of the machine to access the service deployed on the localhost. The vendor recommends that I map the public IP to the localhost in the /etc/hosts. I've done that also. However, I'm still not able to access the service. What else do I need to do? This service works just fine on AWS.

Comment: You need to let the service listen to the 0.0.0.0.

Comment: It does. This works fine in other environments, just not Azure.

Comment: It's the same in the VM. How do you do in the VM?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean ?

Comment: I mean how do you deploy the service in VM?

Comment: I follow the vendors install instructions .... just like I do it on a local VM, a AWS EC2 instance. I follow the same instructions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194806/discussion-between-charles-xu-and-user7676946).

Answer (score 1):

I also had similar issue hosting my app on Azure.
I tried exposing NSG to allow the port of the service but it did not work, then I found the issue in the load balancer associated with the VM.
Steps to allow any port e.g. 80 on Azure VM.

1. Go to your load balancer (https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Network/LoadBalancingHubMenuBlade/loadBalancers) associated with the VM.
2. Go to **Inbound NAT rules** on the left blade and add a new rule to allow port 80  through the Load Balancer.[image][image]
3. Click **Save**

Make sure to expose port 80 in the `Inbound Rules` on the VM.
That should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a rule in NSG to allow the port of the service with the source IP as ANY. So Internet client can access the service.

You need to navigate to the NIC of the VM and find the NSG which is associated with it. Post that add a Inbound rule to allow traffic from Internet to the specific port and check if that works.

Comment: I already allowed all incoming and outgoing from/to any IP, from/to any port. This did not help.

Comment: Can you try doing a telnet to public IP with the port? This will narrow down whether it is an issue with the connectivity or it is an issue with your service.